# Jenkins fails to use unix user/group to do authentication

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins inside Docker container.
Now when i try to go inside "Manage Jenkins >> Configure Global Security' and select "Unix user/group database".

It fails with error "User ‘jenkins’ needs to belong to group shadow to read /etc/shadow".

In the Host machine i did "sudo su jenkins' and then did "ls -l /etc/shadow", i can see the below output
"-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1500 Dec 20 20:24 /etc/shadow"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: does `sudo adduser jenkins shadow` not work?

Comment: the command "sudo adduser jenkins shadow" doesnt work

Comment: instead if i run this  :                                                                                    "[root@wcportal-workplace pramanda]# sudo /usr/sbin/usermod -a -G shadow jenkins
usermod: group 'shadow' does not exist                                                                             it says "usermo"d: group 'shadow' does not exist

Comment: please help am very new here

Comment: Why do you want to use a unix user/group db for this? It seems like the wrong solution when running from docker (though that said: it's not immediately obvious to me why it wouldn't work)

Comment: then what is the correct option to login when running from docker?                                       Isee the below 5 options only:                                                                           Security Realm
 . Delegate to servlet container
 . Jenkins’ own user database
 . LDAP
 . Unix user/group database
 . None

Comment: previously we used to use jenkins and in the old jenkins we used to login as our UNIX/LINUX credentials.  Anyone in our organization could login to the old Jenkins instance using their UNIX/LINUX credentials.

Comment: but inside the docker container you won't have control of the unix creds. The plan wasn't (or shouldn't be!) to docker exec into the container and add users for Jenkins to use! You should instead use Jenkins's own user database or LDAP imo.

Comment: i have aborted the docker way of installing jenkins. Now i am installing jenkins in Linux